# Consistent Blur On Overflow with CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I've got an issue with trying to emulate a frosted glass effect in CSS. I'm able to get the effect to work just fine if the div in question is centered above the background image, but if I ever try to move it to a corner (i.e. so that the 'blur' effect is slightly off canvas), it results in partial failure to blur. I'm assuming that this is because it's not picking up image information to blur, just picking up empty pixels. You can see in a codepen here: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/cipherbeta/pen/pKLNaQ)

Here's the mixin that I'm currently using on the blur div:

```
content: " ";
background: inherit;
background-attachment: inherit;
position: absolute;
height: calc(100% + 50px);
width: calc(100% + 50px);
left: -25px;
right: 0px;
top: -25px;
bottom: 0px;
filter: blur(20px);
```

I'm making a div that overflows the parent div and then is offset by a particular amount in order to give a sharp blur edge.

Is there some hacky solution to let it overflow off the body while still grabbing image information from a image repeat or something?

Comment: How is that off canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your mixin:

```
transform: scale(1.75);
```

This makes the background width and height larger while maintaining the blur effect/sizing.

Comment: For some reason, just adding transform: scale(1); did the trick as well. Appreciate the help!